# regex_replace to append to end of line?

Tags: sql, postgresql, regexp-replace

I have a postgres table which contains rows that each hold multiple lines of text (split by new lines), for example...

The table name is formats, column is called format, an example format (1 table row) would look like the following:

```
list1=text1;

list2=text2;

list3=text3;

etc etc
```

I would like a way to identify the list2 string and then append additional text to the end of the same line.

So the outcome would be:

```
list1=text1;

list2=test2;additionaltext

list3=text3;
```

I have tried the below to try and pull in the 'capture string' into the replace string but have been unsuccessful so far.

```
 regexp_replace(format, 'list2=.*', '\1 additionaltext','n');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture a pattern, you must enclose it in parenthesis.

```
regexp_replace(format, '(list2=.*)', '\1additionaltext', 'n')
```

Comment: Excellent, just tried that and it does work and it passed in the captured pattern. One thing though, although it pulled through the 'captured pattern', a new line was placed after this and then the additional text on line below, is there anyway to stop that from happening so they appear on the same line and not separate lines? 

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1f21e65272d18595feadb96a77fba3fc Text stays in the same line.

Comment: Thing I've sorted it, I was missing a semi colon in my capture pattern which appends the text to the same line!

Thanks for your help :)